# Make a rect object scrollable

Tags: python, pygame, scrollable

I am drawing a chess move log onto a rect object - however after a certain point the text goes off of the bottom and gets cut off. I was wondering if its possible to make the rect surface scroll able so I can see the whole move log.

Here is the code for drawing the move log :

This is what I mean

[image]

As you can see after the 21st move - the log goes off the bottom of the move log area

```
def drawMoveLog(screen, gs, font): #draws move log
    moveLogArea = p.Rect(BOARD_WIDTH, 0, MOVE_LOG_PANEL_WIDTH, MOVE_LOG_PANEL_HEIGHT)
    p.draw.rect(screen , p.Color("gray"), moveLogArea)
    moveLog = gs.moveLog
    moveText = []
    for i in range(0, len(moveLog), 2): #go through move log 2 at a time
        moveString = "|| " + str(i//2 + 1) + ". " + str(moveLog[i]) + " "# to keep move 2 and 2 the same
        if i + 1 < len(moveLog): # before i continue want to make sure black moved
            moveString += str(moveLog[i + 1]) + " "
        moveText.append(moveString)

    movesPerRow = 1
    padding = 5
    lineSpacing = 4
    textY = padding
    #make 3 moves go in 1 line
    for i in range(0, len(moveText), movesPerRow):
        text = ""
        for j in range (movesPerRow):
            if i + j < len(moveText):
                text += moveText[i+j]
        textObject = font.render(text, True, p.Color('Black'))
        textLocation = moveLogArea.move(padding, textY)
        screen.blit(textObject, textLocation)
        textY += textObject.get_height() + lineSpacing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that renders the text in a transparent [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) high enough to contain the full text. To create a transparent *Surface* object you have to set the flag `pygame.SRCALPHA`:

```py
def createMoveLog(gs, font): #draws move log
    moveLog = gs.moveLog
    moveText = []
    for i in range(0, len(moveLog), 2): #go through move log 2 at a time
        moveString = "|| " + str(i//2 + 1) + ". " + str(moveLog[i]) + " "# to keep move 2 and 2 the same
        if i + 1 < len(moveLog): # before i continue want to make sure black moved
            moveString += str(moveLog[i + 1]) + " "
        moveText.append(moveString)

    movesPerRow = 1
    padding = 5
    lineSpacing = 4
    no_of_lines = (len(moveText)+movesPerRow-1) // movesPerRow
    line_height = font.get_height() + lineSpacing 
    text_size = (MOVE_LOG_PANEL_WIDTH, no_of_lines * line_height + 2*padding)
    text_surface = p.Surface(text_size, p.SRCALPHA)

    textY = padding
    #make 3 moves go in 1 line
    for i in range(0, len(moveText), movesPerRow):
        text = ""
        for j in range (movesPerRow):
            if i + j < len(moveText):
                text += moveText[i+j]
        textObject = font.render(text, True, p.Color('Black'))
        text_surface.blit(textObject, (0, textY))
        textY += textObject.get_height() + lineSpacing

    return text_surface
```

Render the full text and use [`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)  to create a new surface that references a rectangular area with the height  `MOVE_LOG_PANEL_HEIGHT`.
The scroll argument is a value in the range [0.0, 1.0] and is used to scroll the text linearly. When the scrolling is 0.0, the top of the text is displayed, and when the scrolling is 1.0, the bottom of the text is displayed:

```py
def drawMoveLog(screen, gs, font, scroll): #draws move log
    moveLogArea = p.Rect(BOARD_WIDTH, 0, MOVE_LOG_PANEL_WIDTH, MOVE_LOG_PANEL_HEIGHT)
    p.draw.rect(screen , p.Color("gray"), moveLogArea)

    text_surface = createMoveLog(gs, font)
    dy = text_surface.get_height() - MOVE_LOG_PANEL_HEIGHT
    if dy > 0:
        text_offset = int(dy * scroll) 
        test_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        sub_rect = p.Rect(0, text_offset, MOVE_LOG_PANEL_WIDTH, MOVE_LOG_PANEL_HEIGHT)
        sub_text_surface = text_surface.subsurface(sub_rect)
        screen.blit(sub_text_surface, moveLogArea)

    else:
        screen.blit(text_surface, moveLogArea)
```

---

Compare the rendering of

```py
moveLog = ["d3", "Nh6", "e3", "Rg8", "f3", "b6", "g3", "a5", "h3", "Ra6", "c3", "g6", "b3", "a4"]
```

with `scroll = 0.0` and `scroll = 1.0`.

[image]

Comment: Wow ! Thanks a lot that works perfectly - Is there a way to interact with this and make it scroll-able where the user can use the mouse wheel to scroll over the move log area and go up or down to see previous moves ?